# How to create an RxJs Observable from a node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5, node-request

Currently can create an observable explicitly as follows:

```
const Rx = require("rxjs");
const request = require("request");

        return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    observer.error(error);
                } else {
                    observer.next(response);
                    observer.complete();
                }
            });
        });
```

Is there a shorthand way to do this with the RxJs library (or another library)?

Comment: `bindNodeCallback` http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback

Comment: You are already doing it with RxJS library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
    return (options) => {
        const boundCallback = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(request, toResponseOnly);
        return boundCallback(options);
    };

function toResponseOnly(response) {
    return response;
}
```

The second function is required to ensure only the response is passed on, otherwise the params to the callback are passed on as an array.